# Build a mongo container and import data

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoimport

I want to build a Mongo container, and insert some data stored in the folder /mongo_mock_data in this container. Here are my lines of code:

```
MONGO_ID=$(docker run --publish-all -d --mount type=bind,source=${PWD}/mongo_mock_data,target=/tmp/mongo_mock_data mongo)
MONGO_PORT=$( docker inspect $MONGO_ID |  jq -r '.[0].NetworkSettings.Ports."27017/tcp"[0].HostPort' )
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost:${MONGO_PORT}
docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --host $MONGODB_URL --db algo --collection train --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/train_data.json --jsonArray
docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --host $MONGODB_URL --db algo --collection calculation --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/predict_data.json --jsonArray
docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --host $MONGODB_URL --db algo --collection train --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/cluster_data.json --jsonArray
```

I have the following error:

> error parsing command line options: error parsing URI from mongodb:///localhost:32773/?replicaSet=mongodb:: error parsing uri: must have at least 1 host

any ideas what Im doing wrong?

EDIT:

If I try:

```
MONGODB_URL=localhost:${MONGO_PORT}
docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --host $MONGODB_URL --db pulse_algo --collection train --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/train_data.json --jsonArray
```

instead of

```
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost:${MONGO_PORT}
docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --host $MONGODB_URL --db algo --collection train --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/train_data.json --jsonArray
```

I have the following error:

> error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally, I solved my issue by dropping the argument --host:

```
MONGO_ID=$(docker run --publish-all -d --mount type=bind,source=${PWD}/mongo_mock_data,target=/tmp/mongo_mock_data mongo)
MONGO_PORT=$( docker inspect $MONGO_ID |  jq -r '.[0].NetworkSettings.Ports."27017/tcp"[0].HostPort' )
docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db algo --collection train --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/train_data.json --jsonArray
docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db algo --collection calculation --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/predict_data.json --jsonArray
docker exec $MONGO_ID mongoimport --db algo --collection train --type json --file /tmp/mongo_mock_data/cluster_data.json --jsonArray
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the third slash in `mongodb:///` a transcription error? If not, then what is happening is that MongoDB is trying to connect to a server at `''` (ie, *nothing*) to a database named `localhost:32773`, rather than a server at `localhost:32773` & the default database.

Comment: This is not a transcription error, but I dont get what you mean? I edited my question with the assignment of MONGODB_URL

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error because of passing option `--csv` instead of `--type=csv` to `mongoexport`. Correction of that fixed this issue.

[mongoexport type options](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/#std-option-mongoexport.--type)

Error message could've been better.